# How to use dd Linux command to download a file from the internet?

Tags: linux, unix, command, dd

Ok, I know this might sound crazy but.
Let's say I am logged in and work on the virtual machine on the server through SSH. I have a link and I want to download a file (1 GB) with dd command.

So how to do that?

For me it has to be something like this

```
dd if="www.speed.hetzner.de/1GB.bin"  of=~/dir bs=20
```

Please tell me, I was looking everywhere and can't find the answer.

Comment: dd can't download files from the network. Any reason you want to use dd for this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually want to use dd for the output processing (writing an ISO file to a block device for example), you can pipe `curl` into `dd`:

```
curl 'http://address.for/your.iso' | dd conv=noerror,sync bs=4M of=/dev/sdX
```

Comment: I would suggest just `iflag=fullblock` and `oflag=sync` with a reasonable block size. I think your command will pad the blocks with zeros - i'm not sure about that though.

Answer (score 0):

`dd` Does not support doing this over the network, you should download your file using `curl` or `wget`:

`wget -O ~/dir/1GB.bin http://www.speed.hetzner.de/1GB.bin`

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my life. =)